# converting from var to dictionary<String,int>

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion

I have a dictionary defined as
`Dictionary<string, int> one`

it has some data and I do the following LINQ on it

`var temp = one.OrderBy(r => r.Value).Select(r => r.Key).Take(5);`

But now I want to convert it back into a `Dictionary

I tried using `temp.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);`

But it tells me: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not a delegate type

How do I do this conversion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because you throw away the `Value` with the call to `Select(r => r.Key)`. You'll need to keep the `KeyValuePair` together if you want to convert it back to a dictionary.

```
var temp = one.OrderBy(r => r.Value).Take(5);

var backToDictionary = temp.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
```

If you still want to have an `IEnumerable<string>` of the keys as in your question, you can use this separately:

```
var tempKeys = temp.Select(r => r.Key);
```

---

The reason you're receiving a seemingly unrelated error message referring to an `IEqualityComparer` is because the compiler is attempting to make a best guess as to which overload you are attempting to call. Its best guess in this case *thinks* you were trying to call [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548554.aspx).

Consider the code you had and the type it produced:

```
IEnumerable<string> temp = one.OrderBy(r => r.Value).Select(r => r.Key).Take(5);
```

This would produce an object implementing `IEnumerable<string>`. Then with your call of:

```
temp.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
```

`r` in this case *is* `string`. The compiler at this point is freaking out because there's no such thing as `r.Key` nor `r.Value`. It recognizes that there are 2 parameters being used, and thus has two possible overloads to pick from for `ToDictionary` ([this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548554.aspx), and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx)). At this point, I'm not sure what the rules are for the compiler to choose one over the other (especially since it cannot infer the types of `r.Key` or `r.Value`), but it chose one of them. (perhaps it's simply the "first" one declared/found? Perhaps it favours direct object inputs over lambda expressions?) At any rate, it chooses the overload requiring an `IEqualityComparer` instead of a `Func<TSource, TElement>` and tells you (naturally) that a lambda expression is not convertable to `IEqualityComprarer`.

In my experience, once you feed the compiler garbage (`r.Key` and `r.Value` in this case), overload resolution kinda goes out the window. *Sometimes* it works out, usually when there is only one overload that matches the number parameters, or at least no ambiguity. But other times you just gotta see past the compiler error and fix the root problem.

Comment: Why does the error talk about `IEqualityComparer`? Shouldn't the compiler just be able to detect that `Key` and `Value` aren't defined in `string`?

Comment: @voithos Most likely the compiler is attempting to make a "best guess" as to what overload you're trying to call. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @voithos I've added a detailed explanation as to why that particular error showed up.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the insight. Reading a bit of the C# spec (section 7.5.3 specifically, on overload resolution), it seems that the compiler uses multiple rules for overloading in general (for instance, rules to determine "better conversion from expression", which includes anonymous functions). However, from what I can tell, the spec only talks about functions that are applicable overload candidates, and doesn't mention the error case...

Comment: @voithos Yeah, the specification is pretty clear about how to resolve overloads when the types are _known_. It's in cases like this however when you feed it ambiguous/unknown types that things go awry. Too bad [guessing is not in the compiler's nature.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBxcalnSzIk&t=0m26s)